# printMax method with array using Java...one thing I don't understand is double result = numbers[0]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning java with Intro to Java Programming 9e with Liang. Why does there have to be numbers[0] as in double result = numbers[0]? What I mean is in the brackets, why does it have to be 0?

```
public class VarArgsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMax(34, 3, 3, 2, 56.5);
        printMax(new double[] {1, 2, 3});
    }

    public static void printMax(double... numbers) {
        if (numbers.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No arguments passed");

    return;
        }

    double result = numbers[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
        if (numbers[i] > result)
            result = numbers[i];

    System.out.println("The max value is " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an index. It specifies which element in the array to reference.

Comment: take care because this question maybe down voted by many peopel

Comment: Does it mean that result, a double value, will take the indexed value of numbers[0]. Does it mean that 0 is the index?

Comment: El-conte De-Monte TereBentitkh, is there a reason why I should take care? I'm trying to understand programming concepts, I thought the community would help.

Comment: Peter - ignore him.  There's nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: @PeterFelixNguyen My advice is, go through on array java lesson first.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about what this means:

```
    double result = numbers[0];
```

Taken by itself, it is just assigning the first element of the `numbers` array to `result`.  The zero is an index value.

The reason for the use of the zero value is that in Java (and *most* programming languages!) arrays are indexed starting from zero, not from one.  So for instance,

```
   double[] array = new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
```

is creating an array whose length is `3` and whose indexes are `0`, `1` and `2`.  Of course, the value of `array[0]` is `1.0`.

---

If you then look at the context, the loop following this statement is examining the other elements of the `numbers` array, from one to the last one (i.e. `numbers.length - 1`), and comparing them with `result`.

So from that respect, the statement you are asking about is "priming" the algorithm ... like you "prime" a pump to get it started.

---

> If we prime the algorithm where numbers[0] will be the first value, then how does this work when the for loop starts with int i = 1, and increases up until i = 3. What happens to numbers[0]?

- If the array has 3 elements, the loop *finishes* when `i` gets to `3`.
- Try and understand what this statement is doing:

  ```
  if (numbers[i] > result)
      result = numbers[i];
  ```
- Pedantically ... *nothing* happens to `numbers[0]`.  You are not assigning anything to it!  You are assigning a value to `result`.  Focus on what happens to *that*.

Comment: If we prime the algorithm where numbers[0] will be the first value, then how does this work when the for loop starts with int i = 1, and increases up until i = 3. What happens to numbers[0]?

Answer (score 0):

this indicates the index of the element in the array, it is zero based, so 0 is the first element